# How to calculate angular acceleration in quaternion form?

Tags: math, rotation, quaternions

Assume there is an object whose orientation is q_1 now and it's rotating at angular velocity q_r (according to some references I guess the angular velocity is 0.5 * w * q_1). It's expected to change its orientation to q_2 and stop rotating over a time interval dt. How to calculate the angular acceleration?

Comment: We can assume that object strictly NOT rotate more than 180 degrees. We measure predicted orientation by q_1 and q_r. Than we calculate difference between orientations predicted and measured. If second assumption that acceleration is const we can calculate acceleration from orientations difference.

Comment: @SZYoo You are using confusing terminology. Angular velocity and acceleration would typically refer to w and wdot.  Quaternion first and second derivative would be q_dot and q_dotdot.  These are two different things.  What are you really after?  The formula you show above 0.5 * w * q is one of the forms for the instantaneous time derivative of a quaternion (qdot) given angular velocity w, which is correct only for certain quaternion conventions. Other conventions have different formulae for this. Either way, this is a quaternion derivative and not angular velocity.

Answer (score 0):

After some effort, I've found a solution but I'm not quite sure its correctness. Here is my induction.

(I don't know how to edit math formulas in StackOverflow so I post a image)

[image]

Here q' is the initial angular velocity.

The part of the induction of which I'm not quite sure is if q(t) = q' + t * q'' is correct.